# Find value in column in another sheet - subject to conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel workbook with a lot of worksheets. In one sheet (INDEX) I need a column with "si" or "no" values (or true/false,...boolean). The value decided by other sheets that contain columns filled with strings like `0gr`, or `10gr`, or `1kg`,... These values are weights of a products.

I need a value TRUE (or "si") in INDEX sheet when, in another sheet all values are `0gr` (or `0`).

Sample:

```
Sheet INDEX
abc------TRUE
bcd------FALSE
cde------TRUE
...

Sheet abc             Sheet bcd              Sheet cde
1-------0gr          1--------0gr          1------------0gr
2-------0gr          2-------100gr         2------------0gr
3-------0gr          3--------0gr          3------------0
4-------0gr          4--------1kg          4------------0gr
```

[image]

Comment: Ok! I try to upload the file

Comment: Thanks, I try to learn english and code, jejejejj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF('Ajuntament Edifici Pral.'!G:G,"*gr")>0,COUNTIF('Ajuntament Edifici Pral.'!G:G,"*gr")>COUNTIF('Ajuntament Edifici Pral.'!G:G,"0gr")),"si","no")
```

for the cell you indicate. However if only the date changes, it would give the same result for all other cells in the same column, even if copied up/down.

Comment: wooooww, nice! I try!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this in the target cells in Book Index

```
=IF([abc]'Adjument'!$G$6=0,"YES","NO")
```

where you will replace Adjument with the sheet name in Book abc, and column and rows as appropriate.

In general, the format is

```
 =IF([WORKBOOKNAME]'SHEETNAME'!$A!1=VALUE,"TRUESTRING","NOTTRUESTRING")
```

where, you may replace everything that is an uppercase character of the 1, except the initial `IF`.

Comment: I upload a image because I don't know whoto change your solution...maybe =IF[D8]'Sheet1'!G6:G10=0,"YES","NO"?

Comment: I can't replicate the full name of your source sheet, it's something like Adjument, so let's call it that. You aren't trying to make it depend on a range but rather a single cell, 1:1, so get rid of any ranges. Check the answer for the update.

Comment: Thank a lot! but, [abc] is a cell on I put the code? I'm super neewbe.. :(

Comment: `[abc]` is the name of the Book, as per your original question. If your book is called Waldo, then replace `[abc]` with `[Waldo]`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula next to your cells `abc`, `bcd`, `cde`.
Assuming your WorkBook name is `abc.xlsx`, `bcd.xlsx` and `cde.xlsx`. Please change it as per your need. you will need to change the sheet names as well.

**For abc:**

> =IF(OR( (COUNTIF([abc.xlsx]Sheet4!$B:$B,"0gr")=MATCH("*",[abc.xlsx]Sheet4!$B:$B,-1)-1),
>   (COUNTIF([abc.xlsx]Sheet4!$B:$B,0)=MATCH("*",[abc.xlsx]Sheet4!$B:$B,-1)-1),
>   (COUNTIF([abc.xlsx]Sheet4!$B:$B,"0gr")+COUNTIF([abc.xlsx]Sheet4!$B:$B,0)=MATCH("*",[abc.xlsx]Sheet4!$B:$B,-1)-1)),
>   "YES","NO")

**for bcd:**

> =IF(OR( (COUNTIF([bcd.xlsx]Sheet5!$B:$B,"0gr")=MATCH("*",[bcd.xlsx]Sheet5!$B:$B,-1)-1),
>   (COUNTIF([bcd.xlsx]Sheet5!$B:$B,0)=MATCH("*",[bcd.xlsx]Sheet5!$B:$B,-1)-1),
>   (COUNTIF([bcd.xlsx]Sheet5!$B:$B,"0gr")+COUNTIF([bcd.xlsx]Sheet5!$B:$B,0)=MATCH("*",[bcd.xlsx]Sheet5!$B:$B,-1)-1)),
>   "YES","NO")

**For cde:**

> =IF(OR( (COUNTIF([cde.xlsx]Sheet6!$B:$B,"0gr")=MATCH("*",[cde.xlsx]Sheet4!$B:$B,-1)-1),
>   (COUNTIF([cde.xlsx]Sheet6!$B:$B,0)=MATCH("*",[cde.xlsx]Sheet6!$B:$B,-1)-1),
>   (COUNTIF([cde.xlsx]Sheet6!$B:$B,"0gr")+COUNTIF([cde.xlsx]Sheet6!$B:$B,0)=MATCH("*",[cde.xlsx]Sheet6!$B:$B,-1)-1)),
>   "YES","NO")

Comment: Thanks!, But, when put on my document, excel return me and error...  :(

Comment: You have to change the `workbook name`, `sheet name` and `column name`.

Comment: I gave you the formula, now its your turn. :)